# How do I trigger a function on submit but delay submit until function completes -JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form which requires two functions to run before it submits.

One function converts a canvas image to a data url so it takes a few seconds.

The main problem is that the form submits before the function completes so no data is sent to the server.

I've tried all sorts of code permutations and they all fail.

I've tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        function_one();
        function_two();
        $('#form').submit();
    });
});
```

I've tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        function_one();
        function_two();
        $('#form').submit();
    });
});
```

They both submit the form without completing the function. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add the code of your functions. If they are synchronous it should work.

Comment: The key to fixing this is in the functions that you didn't provide the code for. In `theory`, the function that creates the data url `could` have some sort of `oncomplete`, `success` type function that you would run the form submission from within.

Comment: I thought about this - but these functions are used elsewhere and I want to keep them clean. Is there some way to wrap these functions inside another function that has these 'success' events?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the functions are being called asynchronously. The quickest and easiest fix would be to add a `setTimeout` function that just holds off for a fraction of a second. That would probably fix your issue the easiest.

Other wise, you need to add success events to place `$('#form').submit();` inside of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PROMISE.JS](https://github.com/stackp/promisejs/blob/master/promise.js). you can add promisejs add a chain and wait other functions to wait for previous promise. you can refer the example [here](https://www.promisejs.org/)